# Automatically test when building gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I don't like to run my tests every time I build my code, since the code itself is slow to run. However, I semi-frequently package it into a gem so I can send it to my co-workers. Is there a nice way (ideally within the .gemspec file) to automatically run my tests?

I've seen the test_files attribute in some people's gemspec code, is this intended for use by the installer?

Comment: Are you already using `rake` to automate tasks for your gem?

Comment: If you do, just add `rake test` as a dependency to `rake gem`.

Comment: I'm not using rake, would that be easier?